# connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL: role "username" does not exist TablePlus

Tags: docker, windows-11, postgresql-12, table-plus

I run PostgreSQL with docker but when I tried to connect it with TablePlus I got an error
`connection to the server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist` 
but I clearly see it in my psql under the Role Name. How to solve it? My PostgreSQL version is 12 and my OS is windows 11

Comment: Can u please share the comamnd you are using?

Comment: I don't understand which command you want to see. In table plus I fillup the input field and then I was trying to connect Postgres which is running on the docker